# iOS - Utility Application Template (Xcode 4.3) with and without Storyboard - Confusion

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, storyboard

when I use the utility application template in Xcode (4.3) without 
Storyboard I see the following code to open the flip side view.

I see that the template created an IBAction called ShowInfo (which is connected to 
the button in IB)

```
#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

When I create another utility application this time with Storyboard I see following code:

```
 #pragma mark - Flipside View

 - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
 {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
 [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
 }
 }
```

Can you explain where the connection is between the code and the button in IB?
Like to understand how the button is executing the code to open the flip side.

Thanks in advance

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is inside the storyboard. It's called a segue, and it is connected to the info button in the lower right of the mainViewController. The segue has an identifier named "showAlternate" and it creates a new modal (with horizontal flip animation) viewController from the class FlipSideViewController.
The FlipSideViewController needs a delegate so it can close itself and you set that delegate in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

[image]

---

have a look at this great turorial: [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 1 (raywenderlich.com)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link, will work through Ray's tutorial.